# How do you properly use a Foreach loop for rows in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Ok so I am trying to loop through a few methods that I placed in this foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                {



                }
```

Now my database has 19 rows so I want it to loop as many times as I have rows. But when I step through and debug the .Rows value is 38 meaning it is reading 38 rows for whatever reason. What am I missing here? Why is the row number 38 and not 19? I am also using the SQL CE with a windows form application if that helps.

Comment: Did you step through the query where you are setting `gv.Rows`?  What have you tried?

Comment: **TL;DR** `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gv.Rows){}` :))

Comment: write to a log and see what's happening.

Comment: The only thing that leaps to mind is if you are using a query to populate your DataGridView that isn't behaving as you expect.  How are you populating the DataGridView?

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you are using to generate your DataGridView. Are you using a SQL stored procedure? Building a query on the fly? Connecting with Entity framework?

Comment: I'm think something like two customers, 19 orders and no ON clause in the join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `foreach` is correct and will have no effect on `gv.Rows`. The problem is elsewhere, probably with your query. `foreach` automatically loops from index 0 to the end of the structure (assuming you don't use `break` to exit the loop prematurely).

Given 38/2 = 19 I'd say you're most likely adding each row twice.

Comment: That was exactly it. There was an area where the rows ended up getting double added and I didn't notice.